# Generic Stacks methods

Tags: java, generics, methods, stack, static-typing

I am creating this stack class with the following methods as shown .

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.EmptyStackException;


    public class SortableStack<E extends Comparable<E>> implements ISortableStack<E> {
        private int N;          
        private Node first;     


        private class Node {
            private E e;
            private Node next;
        }


        public SortableStack() {
            first = null;
            N = 0;
        }


    private ArrayList<E> listOne = new ArrayList<E>();



    public boolean isEmpty() {
            return first == null;
        }


        public int size() {
            return N;
        }
        public void push(E e) {
            Node oldfirst = first;
            first = new Node();
            first.e = e;
            first.next = oldfirst;
            N++;
        }
        public E pop() {
            if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Stack underflow");
            E e = first.e;        // save e to return
            first = first.next;            // delete first node
            N--;
            return e;                   // return the saved e
        }


    public E peekMidElement() {
        if(listOne.size() <= 0){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
        }

        return listOne.get(listOne.size()/2);
        }

    public E peekHighestElement() {
        if(listOne.size() <= 0){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
        }

        return listOne.get(listOne.size() - 1);
        }

    public E peekLowestElement() {
        if(listOne.size() <= 0){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
        }

        return listOne.get(0);
        }
    }`
```

//The interface ISortableStack is [here][1] 
(The comments describe the required method signatures).

[1] :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130901/java-stack-implementation

Now when I try to create the main body class as here :

```
import java.io.*;
public class ExhibitStack<E extends Comparable<E> > {

    E ch;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ISortableStack<E> s = new ISortableStack(5); // Cannot instatiate ISORTABLESTACK
        ExhibitStack demo = new ExhibitStack();
        // Cannot make reference to a non static type
        while ((demo.ch = (E) System.in.read()) != '\n') {
            if (!s.full()) {
                s.push(demo.ch);
            }
        }
        while (!s.empty()) {
            System.out.print(s.pop());
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It throws error at ISortableStack as:Cannot make a reference to a non static type .
and is not able to instatiate the ISORTABLESTACK

I would like to create the menu driven program using the interface. I am bad at Java GENERICS and collections and have been pretty late on submitting the assignment .
Any help/directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant to write ISortableStack<E> s = new SortableStack(); you are not having an issue with Generics here, you cannot instantiate an interface. You can only instantiate an implementation of ISortableStack.

Comment: I understand that this is a Q+A site and anyone is free to ask a question, but you are not going to learn how to program by having others solve your assignments. My hope is that you learn from these answers.

Comment: Thanks for replying , Dru . But , I am learning much more from this than I can from any other text book . Thanks to @ZenMaster ,@Mark Peters and even you for giving such awesome insights .As far doing the assignements is concerned, I'm happy atleast that I m trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: Well, let us know if you get that Works internship with this test, Yonathan. Say hi to Yoshiro. And make sure you give credit where credit's due.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ISortableStack<E> s = new ISortableStack(5); //Cannot instatiate ISORTABLESTACK
```

`ISortableStack` is an *interface* (it specifies the signatures of methods but not the code that goes in those methods) and thus it can't itself be instantiated.  Instead try using your concrete *implementation* class:

```
ISortableStack<E> s = new SortableStack<E>();
```

Now, `E` in `SortableStack` is a *type parameter*: it's a placeholder for some *specific* class, like `String`.  Instead of specifying `E` as the *user* of this class, you need to tell the compiler what `E` should map to for this instance.  It looks like your stack needs to hold characters, so what you really want is:

```
ISortableStack<Character> s = new SortableStack<Character>();

char character;
while ( (character = (char)System.in.read()) != '\n') {
   //...
   s.push(character);
}
```

You don't need `ch` to be a member of `demo`.

Comment: Beat me to it :) @Yonathan in addition to this you're going to have a problem because you don't have a constructor that takes in an `int`.

Comment: Im sure , I will . Any suggestion to improving the code on that ?

Comment: +1 for explaining the answer with enough detail so the OP understands what is really wrong with the code posted in question.

Comment: Have I missed the SortableStack<E>( int ) constructor?

Answer (score 0):

At that specific line (`ISortableStack<E> s = new ISortableStack(5);`) there are several things going on.

Let's sort them out one by one:

> ISortableStack is a raw type. References to generic type
>   ISortableStack should be    parameterized

the problem here is that you are trying to use raw type. The next step would be to parametrize  it:

> Cannot instantiate the type ISortableStack

You are trying to create an instance of an interface - which is of course should fail. Use a class instead.

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E

Type parameters cannot be used in any static context, which your `main` method is.

Other than that - you seem to be missing parts of your code...